# linq to return associated object types

Tags: linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I have a function that returns a JsonResult which should be a list of all object types that are associated to the provided guid. But I'm getting the error

> LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.Type GetType()' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

Is this possible?

```
public JsonResult GetWebObjectTypesByWebObject(Guid id)
{
    JsonResult result = new JsonResult();
    var resultData = (from w in db.WebObjects
                      from r in w.RelatedWebObjects
                      where w.Id == id
                      select new { Type = r.GetType().BaseType.Name });
    result.Data = resultData;
    result.JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet;
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Possibly another `ToList` hangup - maybe try forcing your results into a list.

Comment: still go the same error. ah, i see, tolist then select. let me try that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
public JsonResult GetWebObjectTypesByWebObject(Guid id)
{
    JsonResult result = new JsonResult();
    var data = (from w in db.WebObjects
                      from r in w.RelatedWebObjects
                      where w.Id == id
                      select r).ToList();
    var resultData = data.Select(r => new { Type = r.GetType().BaseType.Name } );
    result.Data = resultData;
    result.JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet;
    return result;
}
```

You loose the deferred execution but it seems irrelevant in this case.